# Copy text between two different sessions of terminal for different users?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, clipboard, gnome-session

I have on my `ubuntu` two users, `user1` and `user2`. `user1` is the main user, but `user2` I use it only for development for a specific project that required it like that.
I use `vim` editor, with the XTERM_CLIPBOARD flag on, so if I am in the terminal logged in using `user1` account, I can copy and paste to/from the system clipboard, using in `vim`'s normal mode the key combination of `"+p`. But if I login with the `user2`, this no longer work because `vim` now is running in the `user2` session, which do not share the clipboard of the `user1` session.

My question is:

```
How can I copy text from `user1` session, say from Google Chrome, 
and paste it in vim on the `user2` session?
```

I see it not logical, but who knows, may be there is a hack for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `xclip` (if not installed already) then from user 1's session save the text you want to copy as a file (e.g. test.txt) and then run the following:

```
cat test.txt | xclip -selection c
```

This will copy the text to the clipboard. Now from User 2's session you can just paste the text into `vim` by any usual method like `<CTL>+<SHIFT>+v`.